# How to remove unwanted vertical spacing between divs

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I've run into a bit of a snag whilst developing the frontend for a website. I'm competent with CSS, but not fantastic. Anyway, I've created a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YM_Industries/eLbUU/) that illustrates my problem.

On each page of my website, at the top of the content section, I have a banner image. I wish to put a two colour divider seperating this banner from the content. (As is shown in the mockup my designer gave me: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d9opotyiyp0yc9o/menus.jpg)

I'd like to do this in pure CSS+HTML, without just chucking an image in. Anyway, I've done so using the following code:

```
<img class="banner" src="http://regency.ymindustries.com/static/images/winelist.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
<div>
    <div style="width:30%; height: 10px; display: inline-block; background: #6C210C"></div><div style="width:70%; height:10px; display: inline-block; background: #E5C697;"></div>
</div>
```

(Please forgive the inline CSS, it's just for demonstration purposes. Also, unfortunately, if I put the second div on a newline and indent it, it creates whitespace)

The issue I'm having is that there is a large gap between the divider and the image. I have tried adding margin: 0px and padding: 0px to all the relevant elements, and the whitespace is still there.

Could someone help me out please?

Thanks,
YM

Comment: Use clearfix method, you can search about this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To me it's a vertical alignment issue. You can try

```
.banner {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
div {
    height: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

That way you don't have to use negative margins (which aren't wrong, just controversial practice).

Check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eLbUU/11/)

Comment: Thanks, I'd tried vertical-align: top; before, but I hadn't set the banner to be displayed as a block.
Anyway, I didn't really want to involve floats as I didn't feel they were necessary, and I was avoiding negative margins because I was worried about how it would look at different screen resolutions.

Answer (score 6):

you can make the position relative and then set the top to something minus. ex:

```
 position: relative;
 top:-10px;
 left:0px;
```

Answer (score 4):

this is actually float problem

```
    <img class="banner" src="http://regency.ymindustries.com/static/images/winelist.jpg">
<div style="">
    <div style="float:left;width:30%; height: 10px; display: inline-block; background: #6C210C"></div><div style="width:70%;float:left; height:10px; display: inline-block; background: #E5C697;"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.banner {
    width:100%;
float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eLbUU/4/

Answer (score 2):

using display block and floating the divs, also making sure the img itself is display block with overflow hidden I was able to tighten up the stripes to the img : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eLbUU/10/)

```
.banner {
    width:100%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div div{
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, put the darker brown in the lighter brown div. That way, when the window is re-sized, you don't compromise the sizing percentage and/or spacing.

```
<div style="width:100%; height:10px; display: inline-block; background: #E5C697;"> <div style="width:30%; height: 10px; background: #6C210C;"></div></div>
```

And with the space, you can either use negative margins or floats like others have mentioned.

```
.banner {
    width:100%;
    /* margin-bottom to the banner is negative which moves the div upward */
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/eLbUU/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Putting display: block; for the image class and float:left; for all other elements may help.

```
.banner {
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bjliu/eLbUU/7/ (Edit: Sorry Wrong Link)